# How to skip over scraping a tag that does not exist on one single page of many in a for loop?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, if-statement, web-scraping

I am looping through some pages scraping the text out of an `<a>` tag. I am using python 3.7.

Everything runs smoothly, except one page, which doesn't have the `<a>` tag that I am scraping. I am hoping to be able to scrape the text I need from each pages's `<a>` tag, and have the script continue after this page that doesn't have the tag.

I tried to get arround the issue by using an 'if else None' statement. But I have not been able to get that to work.

This leads to an Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

```
p = indaplaybox.div.a
P_O = p.text if p else None
print(P_O)
```

The normal HTML for indaplaybox looks like this:

```
<tr class="pncPlayerRow playerTableBgRow1" id="plyr17676">
    <td class="slot_4 playerSlot" id="slot_17676" style="font-weight: bold;">WR</td>
    <td class="playertablePlayerName" id="playername_17676" style=""><a cache="true" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" fpopheight="357px" fpopwidth="490px" href="" instance="_ppc" leagueid="216415" playerid="17676" seasonid="2018" tab="null" teamid="-2147483648">StefD</a>, Mn WR</td>
    <td>
        <div><a class="flexpop" content="ajax#/ffl/format/pvopop/summary?leagueId=216415&amp;positionId=3&amp;playerId=70325&amp;seasonId=2018" instance="_ppc">SF</a></div>
    </td>
    <td class="gameStatusDiv"><span class="gameNotch_380909016_16 onFieldNotch">»</span> <a class="gamestatus_380909016_16" target="_blank">W 24-16</a></td>
    <td class="playertableStat">12.6</td>
</tr>
```

The HTML that is causing the error looks like this:

```
<tr class="pncPlayerRow playerTableBgRow0" id="plyr18225">
    <td class="slot_2 playerSlot" id="slot_18225" style="font-weight: bold;">RB</td>
    <td class="playertablePlayerName" id="playername_18225" style=""><a cache="true" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" fpopheight="357px" fpopwidth="490px" instance="_ppc" leagueid="216415" playerid="18225" seasonid="2018" tab="null" teamid="-2147483648">Kareem Hunt</a>, FA RB</td>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">** BYE **</td>
    <td class="playertableStat appliedPoints appliedPointsProGameFinal">4.9</td>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Seems like the error happens in `indaplaybox.div.a`. Can you share more code to see how it's defined?

Comment: Yea the error comes when it gets to that page. Indaplaybox.div.a works for every other page. What code would be helpful to see?

Comment: I mean what is `indaplaybox` and where it comes from. You need a condition also for `if indaplaybox.div` I guess.

Comment: indaplaybox is cell in a table.

Comment: I added the HTMl code to my initial question if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by not giving the whole code, it limits on how to answer. But I would use `try`

it'll try to set `p = indaplaybox.div.a`. If it can't it'll just continue to the next element in your list

```
try:
    p = indaplaybox.div.a
    P_O = p.text
    print(P_O)

except:
    print ("no attribute 'a'")
    continue
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! This works in the terminal. If I am saving this too csv with a bunch of other variables, how would I save this?

Comment: at the moment my code for saving to csv looks like: with open(filename, "a") as myfile: myfile.write( a + "," +  b )... Would I just add + "," P_O?

Comment: Almost. You’d need + “,” + P_O    Otherwise that looks correct. Did you try that?

Comment: Also, if the solution worked out above, don’t forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Ok so it worked! I was able to run the script with no issue. THe new issue, is that for the row that is unique, it prints in csv the information from the previous row, instead of what I put in the quotations.

Comment: not sure. without seeing the whole code, its tough to know. Sounds like something not in the correct place within your loop. but thats just a guess

Comment: K. I will look into it. Thanks for the help man, really appreciate it :)